# No such method exception when using Smooch android sdk after sending a whisper to ask for rating the app

Tags: android, android-listview, smooch

I am using Smooch.io sdk to build a customer support system for my android app , and I am able to send a message to the support team , however I have configured an auto - response which asks for user rating . But on receiving the whisper the app crashes and further the conversation screen can't be loaded .
Find the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getState()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lio/smooch/core/MessageAction; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.smooch.core.MessageAction' appears in /data/app/com.fedo.app-2/base.apk)
                                                                  at io.smooch.ui.adapter.MessageListAdapter.getItemView(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at io.smooch.ui.adapter.MessageListAdapter.getView(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug only for newest version. I'm return on 2.0.5 and all OK!

```
compile 'io.smooch:core:2.0.5'
compile 'io.smooch:ui:2.0.5'
```